# Passing multiple values in perl cookie

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi, send

I know how to pass one value (variable) in the cookie, but how do I send multiple values in one cookie. Here is how I did my cookie

Sending:

```
my $name = $query->param('name');
print "Set-Cookie:name=$name\n";
```

Reading:

```
$name = cookie('name');
```

Now I have other variables such as height, weight etc.. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways, but this is a cheap and easy one that comes to mind:

```
use MIME::Base64;  # for encode_base64 / decode_base64
use YAML::XS;      # for Dump and Load

# Setting the cookie:
#  -- Put the keys you want to store in a hash  
#  -- encode as follows:
my $cookie_value = encode_base64( Dump( \%hash ) );

print "Set-Cookie:monster=$cookie_value\n";


# To decode the cookie:
#  -- Get the cookie value into a string
#  -- Decode into a hashref as follows:
my $cookie_hash = Load( decode_base64( $cookie_value ) );
```

That would let you put as much as you want in the cookie, up to whatever the maximum cookie length is.

You can find those modules at cpan.org:

- [http://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS](http://metacpan.org/pod/YAML%3a%3aXS)
- [http://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64](http://metacpan.org/pod/MIME%3a%3aBase64)